# How to merge and shuffle array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Having array of arrays

```
var a = [[[1, "alpha", "a"],
          [2, "beta",  "b"]],
         [[3, "gama",  "c"]],
         [[4, "delta", "d"]]];

var b = [];
```

**1)** How can I merge `a[0]` and `a[2]` into `b`?

**2)** How can I shuffle array `b`?

---

This is a shuffle algorithm I am using >>

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    this.push(this.splice(Math.random() * (this.length - i), 1)[0]);
  return this;
}
```

with syntax

```
myArray.shuffle();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To merge you can simply use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
var b = a[0].concat(a[2]);
```

For shuffling you need to write your own shuffling logic. There is no API for such.

Shuffling -

- [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)
- [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.merge( a[0], b );
$.merge( a[2], b );
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery specific function to do this

Look at http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

"Shuffling" is pretty simple:

```
var arry = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arry.sort(function(a,b){
    return Math.random() * 2-1;
});
```

Comment: It'll work with any array of anything, but it's only pseudo random and consecutive "shuffles" have no effect since `Math.random()` is time-based